# PHP : mysqli search from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i am doing a very simple search operation  using php  mysqli , in my database there is a company  name field  that i want to  search  and this is what   i am using

```
SELECT * FROM directory WHERE title LIKE '$sq%'
```

title is what i am getting through `$_POST`
rest of the query is working fine for but there is a problem  if company name is

**Company name**  and if i enter name  that  does not show search results but shows only  first name , how do i fix this need your help please

Comment: Could you show part of your code or just elaborate the problem?

Comment: can you re-explain your problem?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: its unclear , can u revist your question

Comment: problem is that if company name is   coca cola  i need to enter coca to search cola wont give me results hope its clear now

Comment: @Sikander answer worked? No?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wildcard the front the query as. `%` means anything else is allowed on the left and right.

With your current query:

```
SELECT * FROM directory WHERE title LIKE '$sq%'
```

You require the title start with the exact phrase. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM directory WHERE title LIKE '%$sq%'
```

To match anything preceding the search term and proceeding it.

This should be [parameterized](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as well:

```
SELECT * FROM directory WHERE title LIKE ?
```

Then bind `'%' . $sq . '%'`.

More on wildcards: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Simple examples:

`'chri%'` would match `chris`, `chrissss`, `christopher`, wouldn't match `kris`.

`%ris%` would match `chris`, `chrissss`, `christopher`, `kris`.

`%ris` would match `chris`, and `kris`.

Comment: @Sikander improve, ofc you can also use OR operator in Where eg. title like %a% or title like Aa% if you'll need.

Comment: @daremachine `%a%` would match anything `like Aa%` matched.